# How to get field and values from the nested document and ignore arrays and objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the below 2 documents from a post collection. How to get only key value pairs from "post" object. The match condition will be using "post_id".

```
{
   "_id":"1001",
   "post":{
      "country_name":"India",
      "state_name":"Maharashtra",
      "city_name":"Mumbai",
      "duration":"10",

      "country":[
         {
            "name":"india"   
         }
      ],
      "site":[
         {
            "site_no":"101",
            "code":"Taj",
            "name":"santacruz"
         }
      ]
   },
   "post_id":"abcd123"
}

{
   "_id":"1002",
   "post":{
      "country_name":"India",
      "state_name":"Karnataka",
      "city_name":"Bangalore",
      "duration":"20",

      "country":[
         {
            "name":"india"   
         }
      ],
      "site":[
         {
            "site_no":"201",
            "code":"COLES",
            "name":"Coles Park"
         }
      ]
   },
   "post_id":"abcd234"
}
```

The expected result is:

```
"abcd123":{
  "country_name":"India",
  "state_name":"Maharashtra",
  "city_name":"Mumbai",
  "duration":"10"
 }
"abcd234" : {
"country_name":"India",
      "state_name":"Karnataka",
      "city_name":"Bangalore",
      "duration":"20"
}
```

I'm able to filter for one object, but for the bulk and with good performance, can you help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this aggregate query:

The trick here is to create an object with keys `k` and `v` to define the key and value for the next stage.

The key will be `post_id` and the value the object with desired values.

In this case values has to be dinamically created so you can:

- Parse `$post` object to an array, which allows you to filter values inside.
- `$filter` that values to not get arrays or objects using [$type](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/type/).
- Then convert again the array to object using `$arrayToObject`.

And the last step is to use [$replaceRoot](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) so you can get your desired output.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "k": "$post_id",
      "v": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$post" },
            "cond": {
              "$not": [
                {
                  "$in": [
                    { "$type": "$$this.v" },
                    [ "object", "array" ]
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": [ [ {  k: "$k", v: "$v" } ] ] }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FMjXChHwi4K)

Comment: In my case I have more than 100 keys and 50+ objects. So I can't name that in my query.

Comment: I've updated the answer to do it dynamically, hope it helps.